# construction of a Belyi function given its dessin d'enfant

Tags: riemann-surfaces, planar-graphs

The dessin of the Chebyshev polynomial is a path and the dessin of the power function is a star. How to construct a Belyi function whose dessin d'enfant is a tree with a center vertex of valency four and four paths from it with length $n,m,n,m$ respectively?

Comment: Does this help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dessin_d%27enfant#Trees_and_Shabat_polynomials ?